# How to make tool bar selection color visible in Jupyter Lab dark mode?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have been using jupyter lab for my project. But now that I realized that, when I switch to dark mode, all the ticks and closing symbols are invisible because they stay black. How can I change their color to white?

[image: Images for light and dark mode with highlight]

Comment: Which version of JupyterLab do you use? It is perfectly visible in Version 2.1.0.

Comment: @krassowski I tried installing 2.1.0 still the same problem.